# zabbix trapper with result from a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, bash, zabbix

I search to create a zabbix trapper from the result of a mysql query. I have deploy of my network a unix utility arpwatch. Arpwatch record all adress IP , mac of a netwok . I send the record in a database for compare him to a dhcp bail.

The code of my script is that :

```
`#/usr/bin/bash`

 `DB_HOST='192.168.0.13
DB_USER='user'
DB_PASS='test'
DB='arpwatch' `

 `mysql -u "$DB_USER" \ `
   `--host="$DB_HOST" \ `
   `--password="$DB_PASS" \ `
   `--database="$DB" \ `
   `--enable-local-infile \ `
     `--execute="$req1 $req2" `

 `req1=$'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/var/lib/arpwatch/arp.dat" `
              `INTO TABLE arpwatch `
              `FIELDS ENCLOSED BY " " `
              `LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";' `

 `req2=$"select * from arpwatch where arpwatch.adresse_ip not in(select dhcp.adresse_ip from dhcp);" `

if [ "$req2" = "$req1" ]
then 
STATUS="OK"
else
STATUS="WRONG ADRESS"
fi
zabbix_sender  -k network.status -z 192.168.0.13 -s"device"
```

My question is how to make a trigger when the status and when it's possibile to know the wrong adress ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Concept:

```
...    
if [ "$req2" = "$req1" ]
then 
STATUS="OK"
else
STATUS=<DIFF $req2 $req1>
fi
zabbix_sender -k network.status -z 192.168.0.13 -s"device" -o $STATUS
```

=> script will send OK if everything is fine, otherwise difference (IPs with problems, ...)

Trigger:

```
{device:network.status.last(0)}#OK
```

=> trigger will raise event, if last value is not 'OK' - last value (IPs with problem) will be used in notification.

Don't forget: network.status must be *Type of information*: text

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Just i used zabbix 2.2.3 version , and i would used this script for 40 PC. I have read that a can specify the host in the allow host in item mneu exactly. but whit zabbix_sender how make to indicate the 40 pc ?